# No such file to load -- tasks/facebooker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, capistrano, restful-authentication, facebooker

**WORKING UPDATE**

to solve this problem, I simply dragged the tasks/facebooker folder into lib from the venders/facebooker/lib/ directory. The migrations now function.

---

I have a fully tested and [working Rails app](http://github.com/fogonthedowns/Jzsblog) that won't deploy. Its running facebooker and working with restful authentication.

In Capistrano I am getting the following message:

```
latest => /home/fogonthedowns/blog.justinzollars.com/releases/20100710053254
  * executing "cd /home/fogonthedowns/blog.justinzollars.com/releases/20100710053254; rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate"
    servers: ["blog.justinzollars.com"]
    [blog.justinzollars.com] executing command
 ** [out :: blog.justinzollars.com] (in /home/fogonthedowns/blog.justinzollars.com/releases/20100710053254)
 ** [out :: blog.justinzollars.com] rake aborted!
 ** [out :: blog.justinzollars.com] no such file to load -- tasks/facebooker
 ** [out :: blog.justinzollars.com] /home/fogonthedowns/blog.justinzollars.com/releases/20100710053254/Rakefile:9
 ** [out :: blog.justinzollars.com] (See full trace by running task with --trace)
    command finished
```

The file **tasks/facebooker** exists, (see comment below), why won't Capistrano complete this deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This file is already in repository :

http://github.com/fogonthedowns/Jzsblog/blob/master/vendor/plugins/facebooker/lib/tasks/facebooker.rake

Comment: To get this to work I simply dragged the directory into my Lib dir